# Using QGIS Model Designer to get Python scripts, not working?

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I just realised that I could decrease the time needed to create my scripts by using the built-in model tool then extract the scripts. However, when extracting and running the script in the Python console, nothing happens. There are no files created, nor are there any errors reported. Running the script from the model builder works fine.

I might just be missing something, since this i totally new to me.

This is the code:

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : model
Group : 
With QGIS : 32403
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination
import processing


class Model(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('rasterinput', 'raster_input', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination('Raster_aspect', 'raster_aspect', createByDefault=True, defaultValue='C:/Users/tlind/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/raster_aspect_output.tif'))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Aspect
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['rasterinput'],
            'Z_FACTOR': 1,
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Raster_aspect']
        }
        outputs['Aspect'] = processing.run('native:aspect', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Raster_aspect'] = outputs['Aspect']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'model'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'model'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Model()
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the script in the console doesn't do anything, it only defines the script but does not call any functions.

You need to save the script in the processing toolbox. First save the exported model as a .py file, then go to Processing Toolbox -->Scripts -->Add script to Toolbox... and then add the .py file. You can then run the script from there.

[image]

Hope this helps.